# Add meaningful minor ticks to a modified axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This example is specifically relating to plotting data as a function of log(redshift+1) and having a reference redshift axis but can be easily generalised to any functional modification.

I've written a neat little function (with the help of some question/answers on here) that allows me to easily add a redshift axis to the top of a log(1+redshift) plot. I am **really** struggling to get meaningful minor ticks (and would rather not share my dismal efforts!).

Here is the code, including example plot:

In this case, I would like redshifts at every 0.1 increment not occupied by a major tick, with the flexibility of changing that 0.1 in the function call.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def add_zaxis(axis,denomination):
    oldx = axis.get_xlim()
    axis.set_xlim(0., None)
    zspan = [(10**x)-1 for x in axis.get_xlim()]

    denom = denomination
    zmax = int(np.floor(zspan[1]/denom))*denom
    zspan[1] = zmax

    k = len(np.arange(zspan[0],zspan[1],denom))+1
    zs = np.linspace(zspan[0],zspan[1],k)
    z_ticks = [np.log10(1+x) for x in zs]

    axz = axis.twiny()
    axz.set_xticks(z_ticks)
    axz.set_xticklabels(['{:g}'.format(y) for y in zs])

    axz.set_xlim(oldx)
    axis.set_xlim(oldx)
    return axz


data = np.random.randn(500)
data = data[data>0.]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.hist(np.log10(data+1), bins=22)
ax.set_xlabel('log(z+1)')
ax.minorticks_on()

axz = add_zaxis(ax,.3)
axz.set_xlabel('z')
axz.minorticks_on()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Could you provide an example image of the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea would be to use a `FixedLocator` to position the ticks on the axis. You may then have one `FixedLocator` for the major ticks and one for the minor ticks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import numpy as np

def add_zaxis(ax,d=0.3, dminor=0.1):
    f = lambda x: np.log10(x+1)
    invf = lambda x: 10.0**x - 1.

    xlim = ax.get_xlim()
    zlim = [invf(x) for x in xlim]
    axz = ax.twiny()
    axz.set_xlim(xlim)

    zs = np.arange(0,zlim[1],d)
    zpos = f(zs)
    axz.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(zpos))
    axz.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FixedFormatter(zs))

    zsminor = np.arange(0,zlim[1],dminor)
    zposminor = f(zsminor)

    axz.xaxis.set_minor_locator(matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator(zposminor))
    axz.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom='off', top="on")
    axz.set_xlabel('z')


data = np.random.randn(400)
data = data[data>0.]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
plt.hist(np.log10(data+1), bins=22)
ax.set_xlabel('log(z+1)')

add_zaxis(ax)

ax.minorticks_on()
ax.tick_params(axis='x',which='minor',bottom='on', top="off")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: As always, impeccable work @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.
I actually have a version where I  pass in arbitrary functions like your modification (e.g., `f and  invf`) of course, your version is more concise.
I appreciate the help :)